# RShiny Download Button Within RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, shiny

I can't seem to get the shiny `downloadButton` to work in an rmarkdown document with `runtime: shiny`. Here is an example similar to what I am doing.

````
 ---
 title: "R Document"
 runtime: shiny
 ---

 ```{r, echo = FALSE}
 numericInput("SS", "Selecr SS", min = 1, max = 100, value = 1)

 RandomSample <- reactive({
   data.frame(X = rnorm(100), Y = rnorm(100))
 })

 downloadButton("download", "Download")

 renderPlot({
   plot(RandomSample()[(1:input$SS), "X"], RandomSample()[(1:input$SS), "Y"])
 })

 renderTable({
   RandomSample()[(1:input$SS),]
 })
 ```
````

I'd like the download button to download `RandomSample()`, but I can't even get the `downloadButton` to show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [downloadHandler](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadButton.html).

Here is your example with it working:

````
---
title: "R Document"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}

 numericInput("SS", "Selecr SS", min = 1, max = 100, value = 1)

 RandomSample <- reactive({
   data.frame(X = rnorm(100), Y = rnorm(100))
 })

 downloadHandler(filename = function() { 
    return(paste('Example', input$SS, '.csv', sep=''))

 }, content = function(file) {
   write.csv(RandomSample(), file)
 })

 renderPlot({
   plot(RandomSample()[(1:input$SS), "X"], RandomSample()[(1:input$SS), "Y"])
 })

 renderTable({
   RandomSample()[(1:input$SS),]
 })
 ```
````

Note that your filename will not be respected while testing in RStudio, but when running in a browser it will.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks you!

Comment: Great I'm glad! If the answer works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

There's something a bit weird with `downloadButton`. If you look at the function it's:

```
function (outputId, label = "Download", class = NULL, ...)  {
aTag <- tags$a(id = outputId, class = paste("btn btn-default shiny-download-link", 
    class), href = "", target = "_blank", download = NA, 
    icon("download"), label, ...)
}
```

whereas `downloadLink` is:

```
function (outputId, label = "Download", class = NULL, ...) {
    tags$a(id = outputId, class = paste(c("shiny-download-link", 
        class), collapse = " "), href = "", target = "_blank", 
        download = NA, label, ...)
}
```

What that means is the return value of `downloadButton` is invisible, so it won't produce the html to work in markdown (I'm sure that's probably by design for shiny, but if someone can explain why I'd like to know). You can change this behaviour by writing a new function:

```
downloadButtonRmd <- function (outputId, label = "Download", class = NULL, ...)  {
     tags$a(id = outputId, class = paste("btn btn-default shiny-download-link", 
        class), href = "", target = "_blank", download = NA, 
        icon("download"), label, ...)
 }
```

Which has visible output. This might be useful in the case where you have multiple downloads from one document (which is what led me here)

````
---
title: "R Document"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


```{r}
downloadButtonRmd <- function (outputId, label = "Download", class = NULL, ...)  {
     tags$a(id = outputId, class = paste("btn btn-default shiny-download-link", 
        class), href = "", target = "_blank", download = NA, 
        icon("download"), label, ...)
 }
```



```{r, echo=FALSE}

numericInput("SS1", "Select SS1", min = 1, max = 100, value = 1)
numericInput("SS2", "Select SS2", min = 1, max = 100, value = 1)

downloadButtonRmd("down1", label = "Download1")
downloadLink("down2", label = "Download2")


RandomSample <- reactive({
   data.frame(X = rnorm(100), Y = rnorm(100))
 })

output$down1 <- downloadHandler(filename = function() { 
    return(paste('Example', input$SS1, '.csv', sep=''))

 }, content = function(file) {
   write.csv(RandomSample(), file)
 })

output$down2 <- downloadHandler(filename = function() { 
    return(paste('Example', input$SS2, '.csv', sep=''))

 }, content = function(file) {
   write.csv(RandomSample(), file)
 })

renderPlot({
   plot(RandomSample()[(1:input$SS1), "X"], RandomSample()[(1:input$SS1), "Y"])
 })

renderPlot({
   plot(RandomSample()[(1:input$SS2), "X"], RandomSample()[(1:input$SS2), "Y"])
 })

renderTable({
   RandomSample()[(1:input$SS1),]
 })

renderTable({
   RandomSample()[(1:input$SS2),]
 })


 ```
````